# Passing parameters in redirect view Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am not able to get how to pass a parameter along with a main url from a controller. I tried like this:

```
           return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("home?var=ss", true));
```

But I am getting null value for **var** . What is the correct way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[The documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-redirect-attributes) says:

> By default all model attributes are considered to be exposed as URI
>   template variables in the redirect URL. Of the remaining attributes
>   those that are primitive types or collections/arrays of primitive
>   types are automatically appended as query parameters.

So you don't have anything to do except making sure that you have a model attribute named `var`, with the value `ss`.

Comment: Thanks....I got it...i need to add an attribute object named var in modelandview return type.